# Are there infinite-dimensional, artinian C*-algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, c-star-algebras

A ring is **artinian** if it has no infinite descending chains of ideals. Of course finite-dimensional algebras are artinian. I'm wondering if it's possible to have an artinian C*-algebra (or Banach algebra) which is infinite-dimensional. I'm not sure if it suffices to assume the descending chain condition on *closed* one-sided ideals, or if you need it on all ideals.

Of course if artinian implies finite-dimensional then $A$ must be unital after all.

The reason I ask is because I'm wondering if there is a C*-version of the Artin--Wedderburn Theorem:

> If $A$ is a (semiprimitive) artinian C*-algebra then it is
>   $*$-isomorphic direct sum of full matrix algebras over division
>   algebras: $A\simeq \bigoplus M_{d_i}(\Delta_i)$.

Note that semiprimitive (Jacobson radical = 0) is free for C*-algebras, and the only C*-division algebra is $\mathbf{C}$. So my hope is that this would yield that artinian is a direct sum of full matrix algebras over $\mathbf{C}$, hence finite-dimensional.

Some problems I see with this are: how would we know that $\Delta_i$'s are closed in the topology on $A$? If we knew that, we could make the above argument that $\Delta_i\simeq \mathbf{C}$. If we apply the classical Artin--Wedderburn Theorem we get an *algebraic* isomorphism with a direct sum of matrix algebras over division algebras, but it's not clear to me that these division algebras would be finite-dimensional if all we assume is that $A$ is artinian.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you allow only closed ideals, your assumption is far from being true. Indeed there are infinite-dimensional, simple (containing no non-trivial closed ideals) $C^\ast$-algebras and their classification is an active field of research. Examples for infinite-dimensional, simple are the Cuntz-Algebras $\mathcal O_n$.

Comment: In addition, every maximal ideal in a unital $C^\ast$-algebra is closed, so a unital simple $C^\ast$-algebra does not contain any non-trivial ideals. In particular, $\mathcal O_n$ is an algebraically simple, infinite-dimensional $C^\ast$-algebras.

Comment: @MaoWao: Simple algebras are out of the question, since the artinian condition is required on one-sided ideals. An algebra with no nontrivial right ideals is a division algebra, so a C*-algebra with such a property would have to be 1-dimensional. Does $\mathcal{O}_n$ have no nontrivial closed right ideals? I know it should have many not-necessarily-closed right ideals ...

In fact it is true, but "folklore", that there are no artinian Banach algebras. I'm wondering if there is a simple proof in the C*-case.

Answer (score 0):

If a Banach algebra $A$ does not possess an infinite increasing (resp. decreasing) chain of **closed left ideals**, then $A$ is finite dimensional, see Theorem 3 and Remark 5 in [SinclairTullo1974](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01344169). Thus, every Noetherian (resp. Artinian) Banach algebra is finite dimensional.